# Runtime error using VLookup with Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I keep getting:

> a Run-time error '1004' Unable to get the Vlookup property of the WorksheetFunction class

with the Vlookup code below.

If I enable `Microsoft outlook 12.0 Object Library` it works but I run into issues where the code is used with Excel 2013 and adds `Microsoft outlook 15.0 Object Library` references that are not available on excel 2007. I have incorporated late binding which has worked for the most part except for this one bit of code.

I have included a snippet of code which I hope is enough for someone to help me.

```
Sub Button154_Click()

    Dim forename As String
    Dim surname As String
    Dim movedate As String
    Dim callref As String
    Dim dept As String
    Dim deptmove As String
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    forename = Sheet1.Range("f8").Value
    surname = Sheet1.Range("f9").Value
    movedate = Sheet1.Range("k13").Value
    callref = Sheet1.Range("k8").Value
    dept = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Name, Sheet1.Range("K10"), 1)
```

Comment: What is `Name`? Also your lookup range is a single cell...?

Comment: Assuming `Name` is a string, that code works fine for me in Excel 2013 adding no references at all...

Comment: The main sheet has a single cell field that is populated using a Vlookup and I used this code to assign the result to the dept string. I tried adding name as a string and I still get the same error.

Comment: Your code doesn't show any late binding.  How are you performing this late binding?  Excel Add-ins and macros do not carry and references in them.  The references still have to be installed and registered on any computer that doesn't already have them.

Comment: Late binding was used in other parts of the code. My knowledge level for VBA is very poor to say the least so do you have any ideas why enabling the Microsoft outlook 12 object allows the code to work? Do you know how I would include late binding to stop this or am I on the wrong track?

Comment: If you just want the results in K10, why not just use `dept=Sheet1.Range("K10").value`? This method to get the results frmo a cell is cuckoo-bananas. The error you are seeing is because the vlookup function is returning an error like #N/A or #REF. It might be that the result of the `vlookup` in `K10` is an error like #N/A or #REF and the error is carrying through bungling up your VBA.

Comment: If I use dept=Sheet1.Range("K10").value I get back the Vlookup calculation so that's why I used the Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup which returns the vlookup value which is a department name. I tested where the result would not be #N/A and I still get the same error. Again if I enable the outlook 12 reference it works perfectly suggesting the code is ok. When I get the error it shows that specific line of code in yellow so it seems to not like the command Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup.

Comment: Name is a reserved keyword. When you have the Outlook reference chosen it returns "Outlook" as default. You haven't specified whether you want your lookup to return an approximate match (True) or an exact match (False). When Name is blank it returns an error because the lookup is not looking for anything. When you set the reference, it returns whatever is in the cell because it is the closest match to "Outlook" in your range (1 cell).

Comment: Also, can you expand what you mean by 'If I use dept=Sheet1.Range("K10").value I get back the Vlookup calculation'. It should just return the value of the cell. What is in the cell?

Comment: Thanks Dave. Perfect. I added late binding to and changed name to otlApp and it now works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

Added late binding code
Dim otlApp    As Object
Set otlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

An changed the vlookup to:
dept = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(oltApp, Sheet1.Range("K10"), 1)

Now works great